# If possible, how to register front-end and back-end in a single application in Azure AD?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have an application stack with a React SPA frontend and an Asp.net core web-api backend. Both resources had been successfully registered in AzureAD each with its own app and the authentication and authorization processes are working fine. However, would it be possible to use the **same registration** for **both** the front and backend in AD?

When using the AD Application ID from the backend in React:

```
auth: {
        clientId: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>",
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000"
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
ServerError: invalid_request: AADSTS90009: Application 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'(api://xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx) is requesting a token for itself. This scenario is supported only if resource is specified using the GUID based App Identifier.
```

- I am using the MSAL library for the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Both the applications (front end and back end) need to be  registered for sure in Azure AD.

As you are using client id of backend which is api to be secured , the Error is occurring.
Update client-id, tenant-id, redirect URI of front end application not backend api in  configuration file based on application registration in Azure AD.

Then make sure to expose an API and grant admin consent to the API with required permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Your provider configuration looks correct, so check to make you app registration is setup properly. You will need the following things:

1. An SPA platform configuration with a redirect URI of `http://localhost:3000`
2. Add a scope (under 'Expose an API') and make sure your Application ID URI is created
3. Use the new scope in your MSAL authentication template